# VPN Killswitch is blocking my internet (UBUNTU 20.04)

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, vpn, traffic

I uninstalled a VPN while my network was connected to it. But because of its Killswitch I can't connect to the internet.

I deleted the saved vpn Killswitch network located in `Network manager/system network`. Now it connects to the wifi but no internet service.

USB tethering , Ethernet, Bluetooth everything is off. I can't use any of those. Pls help.

**The VPN name was Proton VPN, mine us Ubuntu 20.04**

Comment: What does `sudo iptables -L` show you? Please add the output to your original post.

Comment: Also, what version of ProtonVPN software are you using? The command line app (which version?) or the GUI?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ethernet and WLAN not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1443031/ethernet-and-wlan-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

If you run

```
nmcli device
```

in the terminal, you can see the available connections and there should be the killswitch listed. By removing it you can use the internet again:

```
sudo nmcli connection delete pvpn-killswitch
sudo nmcli connection delete pvpn-ipv6leak-protection
```