# Ethernet and WLAN not working

Tags: networking, 20.04

I have Ubuntu 20.04 on my work laptop and today the internet stopped working, although I still see on the network manager that the Ethernet and WLAN networks are still detected. For information, I have Proton VPN and Cisco AnyConnect for my work VPN installed on my system. I often switch between the two.

As I am typing this from another computer, it will be difficult to copy/paste output of commands, but I will do my best

Comment: To be more precise, it's Xubuntu 20.04

Comment: did you mess with the settings. such as obtain IP automatically to manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be the kill switch from proton vpn, i had this issue a while back and the answer seems to be removing it or just the kill switch:
If you run

```
nmcli device
```

in the terminal, you can see the available connections and there should be the killswitch listed. By removing it you can use the internet again:

```
sudo nmcli connection delete pvpn-killswitch
sudo nmcli connection delete pvpn-ipv6leak-protection
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! This was indeed the problem. Working now :-)

Comment: @Maxclac -please accept the answer if it worked for you. Thank you.